# Is it possible to start other software manager than Discover in Kubuntu when clicking the update button in the panel?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, software-center, update-manager, update-alternatives

Discover software manager has greatly improved, but I still prefer the snappy and simple application Apper. The command `apper --updates` opens Apper, searches for updates and displays them.

Could I associate that command to the update button in the panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Apper can be used to update, but don't take this as a recommendation. First of all, in later Kubuntu the program needs to be started with `env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true apper` in order to get administrative rights. Thus, I still use it to install stuff. But updates can be tricky because of snaps and maybe other new developments in Discover. Thus, Discover or `apt` may be safer.

(Unless you really know what you want and what you do.)

---

This doesn't really answer the question as such, but it's a workaround that gives me almost what is asked:

Create a new launcher: right click the application launcher icon and add a new item. Use a name like "Updates with Apper", a related icon, the command `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true apper --updates` and a comment like "up" or "updates".

[image]

Then, when the update button shows new updates, instead of clicking it, press Super key and type "up" to launch "Updates with Apper".

[image]

[image]

Apper opens with the list of updates. Press "Update", enter the password

[image]

Updates are downloaded

[image]

and installed

[image].

All looks fine, excepting the fact I usually get an error at the end saying Apper has closed, but in fact it's a rather harmless bug and the update panel button is gone:

[image]

I still prefer it to Discover because it's faster.